# nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a rails app running on nginx and passenger.
I want to proxy all the requests coming on the `/cometchat` url to the apache server running on port `81`.

So all requests are

```
/cometchat
/cometchat/xyz
/cometchat/xyz/abc/1.html
```

etc

Should go to the apache server on port `80`.

I have tried the following:

```
location ^~ /cometchat/ {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
}
```

This works only when the request is `/cometchat/`
but does not work when it is `/cometchat/index.html`

And

```
location ~ ^/cometchat/(.*)$ {
         #alias /home/website/files/$1;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
}
```

Both do not work.

Please suggest the correct one.

Comment: Is it the only location in your nginx config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
location /cometchat/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
}
```